# no hdf5 files with armadillo 12.6.2 on macos and cluster

Tags: hdf5, armadillo

I am trying to save an armadillo matrix (mat) to a hdf5 file. I am on a CentOS cluster and using anaconda without root privileges.

### Packages installed

I have created an environment `arma12` in which I first installed hdf5 and then armadillo. `conda env export --from-history` result is

```
name: arma12
channels:
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - hdf5
  - armadillo
prefix: /home/keshav/.conda/envs/arma12
```

and the versions are `hdf5-1.14.2` and `armadillo-12.6.4`. The detailed output of `conda list` is

```
# packages in environment at /home/keshav/.conda/envs/arma12:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
_libgcc_mutex             0.1                 conda_forge    conda-forge
_openmp_mutex             4.5                       2_gnu    conda-forge
armadillo                 12.6.4               h0a193a4_0    conda-forge
arpack                    3.7.0                hdefa2d7_2    conda-forge
c-ares                    1.19.1               hd590300_0    conda-forge
ca-certificates           2023.7.22            hbcca054_0    conda-forge
hdf5                      1.14.2          nompi_h4f84152_100    conda-forge
keyutils                  1.6.1                h166bdaf_0    conda-forge
krb5                      1.21.2               h659d440_0    conda-forge
libaec                    1.0.6                hcb278e6_1    conda-forge
libblas                   3.9.0           18_linux64_openblas    conda-forge
libcblas                  3.9.0           18_linux64_openblas    conda-forge
libcurl                   8.2.1                hca28451_0    conda-forge
libedit                   3.1.20191231         he28a2e2_2    conda-forge
libev                     4.33                 h516909a_1    conda-forge
libgcc-ng                 13.1.0               he5830b7_0    conda-forge
libgfortran-ng            13.1.0               h69a702a_0    conda-forge
libgfortran5              13.1.0               h15d22d2_0    conda-forge
libgomp                   13.1.0               he5830b7_0    conda-forge
liblapack                 3.9.0           18_linux64_openblas    conda-forge
libnghttp2                1.52.0               h61bc06f_0    conda-forge
libopenblas               0.3.24          pthreads_h413a1c8_0    conda-forge
libssh2                   1.11.0               h0841786_0    conda-forge
libstdcxx-ng              13.1.0               hfd8a6a1_0    conda-forge
libzlib                   1.2.13               hd590300_5    conda-forge
ncurses                   6.4                  hcb278e6_0    conda-forge
openssl                   3.1.2                hd590300_0    conda-forge
superlu                   5.2.2                h00795ac_0    conda-forge
zstd                      1.5.5                hfc55251_0    conda-forge
```

### Code

The minimal test code which is used is

```
#define ARMA_USE_HDF5
# include <iostream>
# include <armadillo>

using namespace std;
using namespace arma;

int main()
{       cout<< "Hello world"<< endl;
        arma_version ver;
        cout << "ARMA version: "<< ver.as_string() << endl;
        
        mat A(2,2, fill::ones);
        cout<< A<< endl;
        A.save(hdf5_name("A.hdf5", "A"));
        return 1;
}
```

and is compiled via `gcc/12.2.0` with

```
g++ -std=c++17 -O3 test.cpp -I$(ARMA)/include -L$(ARMA)/lib -Wl,-rpath=$(ARMA)/lib -larmadillo -lhdf5
```

where `ARMA=/home/keshav/.conda/envs/arma12`. This compiles without errors and gives an executable `a.out` , which on `ldd ./a.out` gives result

```
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffc5dffb000)
    libarmadillo.so.12 => /home/keshav/.conda/envs/arma12/lib/libarmadillo.so.12 (0x00002b8a88204000)
    libhdf5.so.310 => /home/keshav/.conda/envs/arma12/lib/libhdf5.so.310 (0x00002b8a88280000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /home/keshav/.conda/envs/arma12/lib/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00002b8a886ac000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00002b8a888a7000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /home/keshav/.conda/envs/arma12/lib/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00002b8a88ba9000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00002b8a88bc4000)
    libblas.so.3 => /home/keshav/.conda/envs/arma12/lib/./libblas.so.3 (0x00002b8a88f88000)
    libarpack.so.2 => /home/keshav/.conda/envs/arma12/lib/./libarpack.so.2 (0x00002b8a8b14e000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000563928b22000)
    libcrypto.so.3 => /home/keshav/.conda/envs/arma12/lib/./libcrypto.so.3 (0x00002b8a8b19d000)
    libcurl.so.4 => /home/keshav/.conda/envs/arma12/lib/./libcurl.so.4 (0x00002b8a8b6aa000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00002b8a8b75b000)
    libsz.so.2 => /home/keshav/.conda/envs/arma12/lib/./libsz.so.2 (0x00002b8a8b977000)
    libz.so.1 => /home/keshav/.conda/envs/arma12/lib/./libz.so.1 (0x00002b8a8b982000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00002b8a8b99d000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib64/librt.so.1 (0x00002b8a8bba1000)
    libgfortran.so.5 => /home/keshav/.conda/envs/arma12/lib/././libgfortran.so.5 (0x00002b8a8bdaa000)
    libnghttp2.so.14 => /home/keshav/.conda/envs/arma12/lib/././libnghttp2.so.14 (0x00002b8a8bf55000)
    libssh2.so.1 => /home/keshav/.conda/envs/arma12/lib/././libssh2.so.1 (0x00002b8a8bf83000)
    libssl.so.3 => /home/keshav/.conda/envs/arma12/lib/././libssl.so.3 (0x00002b8a8bfc8000)
    libgssapi_krb5.so.2 => /home/keshav/.conda/envs/arma12/lib/././libgssapi_krb5.so.2 (0x00002b8a8c06a000)
    libzstd.so.1 => /home/keshav/.conda/envs/arma12/lib/././libzstd.so.1 (0x00002b8a8c0be000)
    libquadmath.so.0 => /home/keshav/.conda/envs/arma12/lib/./././libquadmath.so.0 (0x00002b8a8c1d2000)
    libkrb5.so.3 => /home/keshav/.conda/envs/arma12/lib/./././libkrb5.so.3 (0x00002b8a8c20c000)
    libk5crypto.so.3 => /home/keshav/.conda/envs/arma12/lib/./././libk5crypto.so.3 (0x00002b8a8c2e2000)
    libcom_err.so.3 => /home/keshav/.conda/envs/arma12/lib/./././libcom_err.so.3 (0x00002b8a8c2fa000)
    libkrb5support.so.0 => /home/keshav/.conda/envs/arma12/lib/./././libkrb5support.so.0 (0x00002b8a8c301000)
    libkeyutils.so.1 => /home/keshav/.conda/envs/arma12/lib/./././libkeyutils.so.1 (0x00002b8a8c30f000)
    libresolv.so.2 => /lib64/libresolv.so.2 (0x00002b8a8c316000)
```

i.e. all libraries are linked.

### Problem

But when I execute the file by `./a.out` , the output is

```
Hello world
ARMA version: 12.6.4 (Cortisol Retox)
   1.0000   1.0000
   1.0000   1.0000
```

i.e. it prints the `A` matrix correctly, but the code is halted indefinitely (atleast for 5 mins). On pressing `Ctrl-C` to terminate, `ls` shows that no hdf5 file is created, instead a `A.hdf5.tmp_*` file is created after each run.

Note: my CentOS supports anaconda version `2021.11` with conda version `4.10.3`, which I am using. Any higher version of anaconda can't be installed because of `GLIBC` version.

### Steps taken

I was expecting a simple hdf5 file. This code runs if the `A.save(hdf5_name("A.hdf5", "A"));` is commented, (or replaced by saving to dat file, with no halting) but no hdf5 files either.

I tried a bunch of things

1. run the code on a local machine with `arma-12.6.4`. Here, I am not using anaconda and armadillo is installed via cmake and hdf5 via homebrew. I ran this on Macbook Air M1. `arma-12.6.4` can't find hdf5 by default. The hdf5 is in `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/hdf5/1.14.2`, and

```
g++ -std=c++17 test.cpp -DARMA_USE_HDF5 -larmadillo -lhdf5 -lm -Wl,-rpath,/opt/homebrew/Cellar/hdf5/1.14.2/lib/ -I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/hdf5/1.14.2/include -L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/hdf5/1.14.2/lib
```

executes. But `./a.out` gives `zsh: segmentation fault  ./a.out`.

2. run the code on a local machine with `arma-11.4.4`, which is installed via cmake after deleting all instances of `arma-12.6.4`. Here there was no problem. `g++ -O2 -std=c++17 -larmadillo test.cpp` gave an executable file , which gave file `A.hdf5` with termination instantly.
3. Installed `arma-11.4.4` in new environment named `arma11`, but the same problem remained there. the executable file is linked similar as with `arma12` but with `arma11` libraries. No hdf5 file, and no termination was seen.

I have no idea to how to make `arma-12.6.4` work with hdf5, either locally or remotely. While `arma-11.4.4` runs locally, please help me to how to run it on cluster with hdf5. Everything else (diagonalization and arma computations) runs well in both and all cases. I guess conda hdf5 installation has some issue, along with `arma-12.6.4` version.

Edit: Thanks to @mtall I was able to clear the local version problem. The issue in the cluster is still unclear. I have updated the question accordingly

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](https://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#save_load_mat) states: "HDF5 support can be enabled by defining `ARMA_USE_HDF5` before including the armadillo header" and "link with the HDF5 library".

So try the following in your program:

```
#define ARMA_USE_HDF5
#include <armadillo>
```

Then add `-lhdf5` to your compiler flags.  For example:

```
g++ program.cpp -o program -O2 -larmadillo -lhdf5
```

If the HDF5 library is not in the regular system path, you will need to specify the path using the `-L` flag.

Comment: I though `-DARMA_USE_HDF5` gives the same effect, so I didn't use it earlier. On your suggestion though I tried it both on the cluster and local. It worked locally on the MacOS armadillo 12.6.4 version. Thank you very much. But the no termination problem, along `filename.hdf5.tmp_*` kind of files instead of hdf5 files in the cluster still persists. Thank you very much. Do you have any clue why hdf5 file is always open and never closed in the cluster. Thank you agian.

Comment: Try downgrading (or upgrading) the hdf5 library on the cluster. Another problem may be that the version of CentOS on the cluster is simply too old. If it's CentOS 7, ask the administrator to upgrade to Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8 or an equivalent like AlmaLinux 8 or Rocky Linux 8.

Comment: It's CentOS 6.6, and will ask the administrator to upgrade. Will try the downgrading hdf5 library. Thank you.